# How to access my NAS via Samba without a username/password?

Tags: linux, passwords, nas, samba

In Windows I can access my NAS via Windows Explorer with something like:

```
//MyNAS/Path/To/Files
```

This does not require a username or password. In fact, I've never configured my NAS to *have* a username or password.

If I want to configure a linux device to access the NAS via Samba it seems to require a username & password.

Is it possible for me to do this without a username or password?

Comment: Do you have root ssh access to your NAS?

Comment: @sgtbeano the NAS is Windows-based

Comment: Unless your NAS isn't Windows? In which case, why would you access your Linux NAS with SMB?

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows Share permissions, ensure that

- Guest account
- Everyone group
- ANONYMOUS_LOGON

have Full Control. Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

Do the same for NTFS permissions:

[image]

Obviously adjusting the actual security objects to match what I've indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount the NAS and not require a username/password, you can mount it as a guest.

Mount the NAS as a guest share, as follows.

Make a folder on the Desktop called `myNas` and type the following into the terminal:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.1.15/Public /pi/Desktop/myNas
```

You can then navigate to the folder `/pi/Desktop/myNas` and view the contents of the NAS there.

While this works, it doesn't automatically mount the NAS at start up. To do that, modify the file `/etc/fstab`, adding a line to the bottom:

```
//192.168.1.15/Public /pi/Desktop/myNas cifs guest 0 0
```

If you *do* want to specify a username/password, you can configure a user on the NAS (usually by browsing to the NAS's configuration interface) and specifying the username & password from there)